# django: urllib2 returns "incomplete format" retrieving JSON

Tags: django, json

I have a piece of code that runs ok via console but fails when running on my django app:

```
# myapp/utils.py
def get_currencies_json():
try:
    req = urllib2.Request("http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open(req)
    return simplejson.load(f)
except Exception, ex:
    logging.error("get_currencies_json(): %s" % ex)
    return False
```

This fails when it gets to f = opener.open(req) and returns this:

```
get_currencies_json(): incomplete format
```

I load this function in a view like this:

```
context = {
    ...
    'currencies_json': get_currencies_json(),
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I've tested this code in a sample Djnago app and it works fine. Do you run the console and django app on the same machine? If not - then it could be that the machine has some restrictions and cannot load the URL? The error itself probably means that the Request gets something different the expected JSON result. Or might be some error in the URL, check again the code...

Comment: I didn't manage to understand what caused the error but I solved my issue just using request instead.